# Catch ReflectionException before command

Tags: php, symfony

I have this service :

```
services:
    resource.entite:
        parent:    "api.resource"
        arguments: [ "AppBundle\\Entity\\entite" ]
        tags:      [ { name: "api.resource" } ]
```

I made a Console Command that checks if an entity exists if its service is declared . It works when the entity is there but when it doesn't I get a ReflectionException.

What I want to do is to be able to catch

> [ReflectionException]                                       Class
>   AppBundle\Entity\entite does not exist

I tried with this Console listener but it doesn't work :

```
class OnCommandListener {

    private $kernel;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel) {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    public function onCommand(\Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent $event) {

        try {
            if ($event->getCommand()->getName() == ('check:entity'))
        } catch (\ReflectionException $exc) {
            dump($exc->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: The `ConsoleCommandEvent` is only dispatched before the command is executed. What you probably mean is the `ConsoleExceptionEvent`. However, this does not prevent the exception from being rethrown. So you will better want to change your command to properly deal with not existing classes.

Comment: Thank You , I'll try that .